# Как изменить расположение превью с горизонтального на вертикальное в Fotorama 4?

Tags: вёрстка, изображения, gallery

Как изменить расположение превью на вертикальное (слева превью, справа фото).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-transition="crossfade">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/300">
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.fotorama {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
.fotorama.fotorama--fullscreen .zoomImg {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.fotorama.fotorama--fullscreen .fotorama__html > div {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.fotorama.fotorama--fullscreen .fotorama__html > div img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.fotorama .fotorama__fullscreen-icon {
  background: #000;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transform: none !important;
}

/* .fotorama__loaded--img img{max-width:100%;} */
.fotorama__nav-wrap {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.fotorama__nav-wrap .fotorama__nav {
  text-align: left;
}
.fotorama__nav-wrap .fotorama__img {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.fotorama__html > div {
  width: 100%;
}
.fotorama__html > div img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-transition="crossfade">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/300">
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```